# Creating a process from within an instance of Jetty that was launched from Maven

Tags: java, spring, jetty, maven-2

I'm looking to launch a separate Java process from within an instance of a Spring controlled bean that runs in a Jetty container.  The Jetty instance was launched from `mvn jetty:run`

This separate process communicates with the launching process via RMI and I'd like to be able to maintain a hook to the process's ID or Process object so that I can kill it later if I need to.

The way we are currently launching this process is to maintain a second list of jar dependencies as a Spring controller property of the launching bean.  This is not a long term solution as it forces us to change versions of Jars twice (once in the `pom.xml`, once in the `applicationContext.xml`).  This list is then used to buildup a class path and calls `Runtime.exec` to create the process.

Comment: I'm curious as to what you're actually trying to achieve here? This smells like a problem I have solved in different flavors earlier

Comment: Hi,
I'm trying to launch a new process from within a web app.  I don't have a classpath that I can use process builder with.  My guess is I need to use something from within Maven or to manipulate the ClassWorld / ClassRealm class loaders to launch this new process, but I'm not sure if that is right

Answer (score 1):

Use [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).